# Windows Forms C# WMPLib Crashes while playing a mp3 file

Tags: c#, windows, forms, mp3

I'm working on a simple mp3 player. I'm using WMPLib for playing mp3 files.

I'm displaying all tracks in Data Grid View, where double click plays selected track. The program plays the right song, however once I start scrolling or pressing buttons fairly quickly the song stops playing.

This is the method which I'm using for playing individual tracks:

```
public static void playTrack(int t)
{
    Library l = new Library();
    WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer song = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
    song.URL = l.myLibrary[t].Patch;
    song.controls.play();
}
```

I call the above method when `dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick` is raised in a separate class.

*Do you guys know why this is happening?*
*Do I need to use multi threading in order to fix it?*

I also thought that my program's UI is simply too "heavy" as I'm using multiple nested panels in custom controls. I'm including a print screen of my running application.

[image]

Comment: WMP is a very expensive component.  Your machine will croak under the weight of all these objects, the GC does not run often enough to clean them up.  Create only *one* instance of WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer, it can play any song you need.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, i found the answer to my problem. 
Just needed to declare Library and WMPLib as a field outside of my method as shown below:

```
static Library l;
        static WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer song; 
        public static void playTrack(int t)
        {
            l = new Library();
            song = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
            song.URL = l.myLibrary[t].Patch;
            song.controls.play();
        }
```

I hope this helps someone :)